# Apex Trigger error INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, You don't have permission to share this file

Tags: apex, trigger, permissions

I am getting the following error while inserting feed items.

> Apex Trigger error INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, You don't have permission to share this file.

This is coming while doing insert DML operation on feed item object.

Comment: Please check the object level access CRUD for the user

Answer (score 2):

FeedItem is a generic object represents any feed.The main reason for using an object-specific feed object is that the generic FeedItem needs a high permission [Click Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm)

You have “View All Data” permission, you can directly query for a FeedItem.

Most users don't (and shouldn't) have that permission, so if you write some code a user can initiate that references FeedItem, you will get an error if they don't have View All Data. But they can query CaseFeed if they have access to Cases.