# Test class with the class Feeditem only fails in migration toolkit

Tags: apex, unit-test, migration-tool, feeditem

We are using the standard class Feeditem to upload documents from our customer portal to salesforce. We made a custom class where we use the Feeditem. We have a test class for that class and it works when we run it from salesforce UI. When we run test with migration toolkit, it fails with this error:

```
TEST_COMP_VehicleDetailsController.test_uploadContract -- System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, You don't have permission to share this file.: []
Stack trace: Class.COMP_VehicleDetailsController.createFeedItem: line 198, column 1
Class.COMP_VehicleDetailsController.uploadContract: line 147, column 1
Class.TEST_COMP_VehicleDetailsController.test_uploadContract: line 185, column 1
```

On te line 198 and 199 in the class COMP_VehicleDetailsController we have this code:

```
FeedItem elm = new FeedItem(Title = 'Uploaded contract document', Body = recordId, ParentId = recordId, RelatedRecordId = contentId, Type = 'ContentPost', Visibility='AllUsers');
insert elm;
```

Does anybody have an idea what could cause the problem?

Comment: I would make sure the salesforce user that jenkins use has all the necessary permission sets assigned or belong to particular profiles.

Comment: The jenkins user is a system admin user, he has all the necessary permissions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/143244/apex-trigger-error-insufficient-access-on-cross-reference-entity-you-dont-have)?

Comment: It works if I login with the migration tool user in salesforce and use the UI, but when I use the migration tool with the user, it fails.